# PHP mysqli Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null

Tags: php, mysqli, fatal-error

Im getting this error and i dont know how to fix.

`'Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\lib\db.php on line 46'`

Code:

```
class db {

public $mysqli;

function Connect() {

         $server = 'localhost';
        $dbusername = 'root';
        $database = 'cms';
        $dbpassword = 'lopaka';
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($server, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $database);

        /* connectie bekijken */
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connectie mislukt: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }
    }


function GetGallery() {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM menu";
    $action = $this->mysqli->query($query);

    while ($row = $action->fetch_assoc()) {
        $gallery .= '<a href="'.$siteurl.''.$row['url'].'" title="'.$row['alt'].'" data-gallery="" ><img src="'.$siteurl.''.$row['url'].'" width="75px" height="75px"></a>';    
    }

    return $gallery;
}
```

}

Thanks !!!

Edit - works now, but now i have some new errors:

Notice: Undefined index: url in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\lib\db.php on line 42

Notice: Undefined index: alt in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\lib\db.php on line 42

Notice: Undefined index: url in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\lib\db.php on line 42

Comment: Please add your use case, you may have not called the `Connect()` method before getting the gallery!

Comment: $db = new db();
$db->Connect();
$db->GetGallery(); that works for now, but now im getting new errors

Comment: Insert `var_dump($row);die();` as the first statements in the `while()` loop, and report back!!

Answer (score 0):

You should add __construct() method to your class...
add like this...

```
public function __construct()
{           
    $this->Connect();
}
```

Here the Connect() will initialized and then only mysqli query() method will work.

Answer (score -2):

```
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($action)) {
            $gallery .= '<a href="'.$siteurl.''.$row['url'].'" title="'.$row['alt'].'" data-gallery="" ><img src="'.$siteurl.''.$row['url'].'" width="75px" height="75px"></a>';    
        }
 return $gallery;
```

Comment: This is wrong and apart from that the error occurs *before* this section.